# Including facebook event on page throws errors

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm trying to embed a facebook event on my website. I got the code from facebook with the 'embed event' button, but it keeps throwing errors: `Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.`, `FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().` and `This Facebook post is no longer available. It may have been removed or the privacy settings of the post may have changed.`

This is the code:

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div> 
<script>(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-post" data-href="#" data-width="466">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <a href="#">Post</a>
        by 
        <a href="#">User</a>.
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: I replaced all href's with "#" for the sake of my privacy :P

Answer (score 0):

If your website is based on a Wordpress installation please double check your post page source code. If the `<script>` tag was stripped probably it's caused by the user's permissions. Try to embed a facebook post as Wordpress administrator and it'll work. In my case that was the stupid problem...

Comment: Well, it's not a wordpress site. This is so strange. Still haven't figured out the problem...